# Unable to add a new Object to document

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to add a new field productFiles(along with its field) to an existing document in MongoDb. 
But I am getting follwing error:

> "the positional operator did not find the match needed from the
>   query."

```
query := bson.M{
     "productId": productId,
}

update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{ 
        "productFiles.$.updatedOn": int32(time.Now().Unix()),
        "productFiles.$.updatedBy": userId,
    },
}

err := repo.Collection().Update(query, update)
```

Comment: Please include an example document you wish to extend, and the expected outcome (the extended document).

Comment: You are querying productId in the top level document, but then you use the positional operator on a totally different field. If you are looking for `productId` within a `productFiles` array of objects, you should query for `productFile.productId`.

Comment: Example document may contain just productId. And expected document would contain additional productFiles field, as shown above.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg productFiles field don't exist. I wish to add it to a document with given productID. So I want to query the top level document and add a new field(productFiles) if the productId matches. Please help!

Comment: In this case: Simply leave out the `$` operator.

Comment: Thanks it worked